# CSS Conflict with jQuery scrollintoview() plugin in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a site that uses the scrollintoview plugin (https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview), but there is some sort of conflict going on with the CSS. I have a fiddle w/o CSS that works as expected and one with CSS that does not. Any ideas about what sort of properties I'm missing that are causing conflicts? There's more information in the info of the fiddles. Working (no CSS): http://jsfiddle.net/beej/vEGxg/1/     Non-working (w/ CSS): http://jsfiddle.net/beej/vEGxg/

NOTE: I only experience this in Chrome. All other browsers (IE8-9 and FF) seem to behave as expected, with the element scrolling into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the non-working jsfiddle, remove the "position:absolute;" property near line #7 inside this CSS block:

```
.background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background:#042F62 url(../images/bg.jpg) top center no-repeat
}
```